# How to wait for characters from UART and transmit back on the UART in ARM Cortex -M3 emulated by Qemu

Tags: assembly, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m, microprocessors

I am trying to do the echo of the data received on the UART, i.e wait for the characters from the UART and transmit it back on the UART. I am emulating the  LM3S811 board in QEMU. I have attached the .c file and the startup and linker code. I get errors while compiling the .c file and I  don't know whether the approach is the correct to do the echo of data received on the UART. It would be helpful if any links explaining the bare-metal programming from scratch are provided. Thanks.

main.c

```
#define  U0RBR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C000))
#define  U0DLL (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C000))
#define  U0THR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C000))
#define  U0LCR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C00C))
#define  U0DLM (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C004))
#define  U0LSR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C014))

void UART0_init(void);
unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void);
void UART0_TxChar(char ch);

void UART0_init(void)
{
    volatile unsigned int PINSEL0 = 0x0;

    PINSEL0 = 0x00000005;
    U0LCR = 0x83;
    U0DLM = 0x00;
    U0DLL = 0x61;
    U0LCR = 0x03;
}


unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void)
{
    while ((U0LSR & 0x01) == 0);
        return U0RBR;
}

void UART0_TxChar(char ch)
{
    U0THR = ch;
    while ((U0LSR & 0x40) == 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    char receive;

    UART0_init();
    while (1) {
        receive = UART0_Rxchar();
        UART0_TxChar(receive);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

startup.s

```
.thumb
.global start
start:
.word 0x20001000
.word main
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00010000
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00002000
}

SECTIONS 
{
    .text : {
        *(.vectors);
        *(.text);
        etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata);
    } > FLASH

    .data : {
        sdata = .;
        *(.data);
        edata = .;
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH


    .bss : {
        sbss = .;
        *(.bss);
        ebss = .;
    } > SRAM
}
```

Errors while compiling the  .c file
command : arm-none-eabi-gcc -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m3 - c main.c -o main.o

```
main.c:7:2: error: 'PINSEL0' undeclared (first use in this function)
  PINSEL0 = PINSEL0 | 0x00000005;
  ^
main.c:7:2: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
main.c:8:2: error: 'UOLCR' undeclared (first use in this function)
  UOLCR = 0x83;
  ^
main.c:9:2: error: 'U0DLM' undeclared (first use in this function)
  U0DLM = 0x00;
  ^
main.c:10:2: error: 'U0DLL' undeclared (first use in this function)
  U0DLL = 0x61;
  ^
main.c:11:2: error: 'U0LCR' undeclared (first use in this function)
  U0LCR = 0x03;
```

After adding the register's address in Qemu only character 'a' gets printed and I am unable to type in the terminal. The command invoked was qemu-system-arm -M  lm3s811evb -kernel main.bin -monitor stdio

Comment: You apparently forgot to include the header containing your register addresses.

Comment: pretty sure it doesnt have a 16550 uart...read the documentation for the part. (after you fix the code and define the registers).

Comment: @Jester . Thanks for the comment, but I am unable to get the register address of U0LSR, UODLL, could you please provide any link or help find the address of registers.Thanks.

Comment: the documentation for the part contains the addresses to each of these registers.  simply googling the part number will suffice, or go to ti.com then search for LM3S811 and download the datasheet, for this part on this site that one document contains both addresses and register descriptions (some vendors/parts there is a datasheet and one or more separate reference manuals required for the whole picture).

Comment: @old_timer Thanks sir, I have edited the answer, and even after the register's address I get only character 'a' printed in the terminal. Could you please help me with this, as I am working on this for a very long time and unable to get the desired result. Thanks.

Comment: well you have the documentation so you already know the data register, you now need to look at the status register (uart_fr or something) and look for rx not empty (examine the rx empty status and if it is not empty then read the next character).  likewise look for tx not full wait for not full then you can send a character.

Comment: its a sim so you probably dont need to accurately set up the part (enable uart0, enable gpio, configure gpio pins for uart alternate function, configure uart baud rate, bits, parity, stop bits, etc)  we know to tx you dont need to do this so probably dont need to do this to receive, etc.

Comment: @old_timer,  Thanks sir, when I looked into the documentation there is no register like UOLSR, UODLM, UODLL. I am confused about whether I am going in the right path. It would be helpful if any code snippet is provided. Sorry for disturbing you again and again. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218299/discussion-between-paulson-raja-l-and-old-timer).

Comment: The document I downloaded from ti Table 2-4. Memory Map shows the base address for things like UART0.  And then the register descriptions for the UART are in chapter 11.   Including reset values, but a UART you normally write the whole register rather than read-modify-write (a gpio for example where a register covers many/all of the pins and you only want to mess with one pin and would do a read-modify-write).

Comment: between this and the prior question you have all you need.

Comment: actually looking again, this document is nxp style, it gives you the base address in each register description you dont need to go look at the memory map, just go straight to the register description.