# How to echo the data in the UART in ARM CORTEX-M3

Tags: assembly, arm, microcontroller, cortex-m, microprocessors

I am trying to wait for the characters from  UART, and then transmit back to the UART, I have attached the .c file, startup, and the linker code. I emulating the LM3S811 ARM Cortex-M3 board using the Qemu. But my qemu gives the following error. Actually this is my extension of the previous post
[How to wait for characters from UART and transmit back on the UART in ARM Cortex -M3 emulated by Qemu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63002788/how-to-wait-for-characters-from-uart-and-transmit-back-on-the-uart-in-arm-cortex)

ERROR :

```
(qemu) qemu-system-arm: Trying to execute code outside RAM or ROM at 0xbf00e000
This usually means one of the following happened:

(1) You told QEMU to execute a kernel for the wrong machine type, and it crashed on startup (eg trying to run a raspberry pi kernel on a versatilepb QEMU machine)
(2) You didn't give QEMU a kernel or BIOS filename at all, and QEMU executed a ROM full of no-op instructions until it fell off the end
(3) Your guest kernel has a bug and crashed by jumping off into nowhere
```

main.c

```
#define  U0RBR (*((volatile unsigned char *) 0x4000C000))
#define  U0THR (*((volatile unsigned char *) 0x4000C000))
#define  U0LSR (*((volatile unsigned char *) 0x4000C004))

unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void);
void UART0_TxChar(char ch);

unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void) 
{
    while( (U0LSR & 0x01) == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    return U0RBR;
}

void UART0_TxChar(char ch) 
{
    U0THR = ch;
    while( (U0LSR & 0x40) == 0 ) {
        continue;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char receive;
    
    while(1) {
        receive = UART0_RxChar();
        UART0_TxChar(receive);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

startup.s

```
.global start
start:
.word 0x20001000
.word main
```

flash.ld

```
MEMORY
{
    FLASH (rx) : ORIGIN = 0x00000000, LENGTH = 0x00010000
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00002000
}


SECTIONS 
{
    .text : {
        *(.vectors);
        *(.text);
        etext = .;
    } > FLASH

    .rodata : {
        *(.rodata);
    } > FLASH

    .data : {
        sdata = .;
        *(.data);
        edata = .;
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH

    .bss : {
        sbss = .;
        *(.bss);
        ebss = .;
    } > SRAM
}
```

The updated code

```
#define  UARTDR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C000))
#define  UARTFR (*((volatile unsigned int *) 0x4000C018))

unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void);
void UART0_TxChar(char ch);

unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void) 
{
    while( (UARTFR & 0x01) == 0);
        return UARTDR;
}

void UART0_TxChar(char ch) 
{
    UARTDR = ch;
    while ( (UARTFR & 0x40) == 0);
}

int main(void)
{
    char receive;
    
    while(1) {
        receive = UART0_RxChar();
        UART0_TxChar(receive);
    }
    while(1) continue;  
}
```

Output : The terminal does not allow me to type anything in the terminal.

Comment: What does your interrupt vector table look like?  This looks like there is code in the  interrupt vector table that is interpreted as an address (0xbf00e000 decodes to `b .+4; nop`)

Comment: where are you getting these LSR, RBR?  This is not a 16550 clone, read the documentation.  UARTFR at address 0x4000C018 is the register you poll for rx and tx buffer status.  offset 0x0004 contains error status not buffer status.

Comment: if you return from main with that vector table then you will crash.  Granted that code doesnt return

Comment: once you sort out the addresses and status bits.  TX polling usually involves waiting for an available slot in the tx buffer (not full) and then writing a character.  This makes for better performance because things are happening in parallel. At the same time characters are in flight so you would need to use a different status bit to flush the buffer.  The approach as written (with the addresses and maybe bit in the register) will work just fine.  pros and cons, good vs bad is based on personal preference/goals.

Comment: when I tested the sim myself I had issues with the uart rx, which I suspect is a sim bug, but not worth the time to debug.  you can easily make this code function if you use the right registers (addresses) and bits. rx and tx does work.

Comment: what part of the documentation are you not understanding?

Comment: @old_timer, Sir, I am very new to this, I read the documentation but it does not help me as there are many jargon words, So I thought I would practice these and learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void) 
{
    while( (UARTFR & 0x01) == 0);
        return UARTDR;
}
```

bit 0 is marked as reserved, so this code won't do anything useful.

Bit 4 though says

> RXFE
>
> UART Receive FIFO Empty
>
> The meaning of this bit depends on the state of the FEN bit in the UARTLCRH register.
>
> If the FIFO is disabled, this bit is set when the receive holding register
> is empty.
>
> If the FIFO is enabled, this bit is set when the receive FIFO is empty.

so independent of the FEN control bit.  Bit 4 is set when the fifo is empty which means when it changes from one to zero at least one character has been received.
So

```
unsigned char UART0_RxChar(void) 
{
    while( (UARTFR & 0x10) != 0) continue; //while empty wait
    return UARTDR;
}
```

Bit 5 is set when the tx buffer is full which means there is no more room.  So

```
void UART0_TxChar(char ch) 
{
    while ( (UARTFR & 0x20) != 0) continue; //while full wait
    UARTDR = ch;
}
```

you could instead

```
void UART0_TxChar(char ch) 
{
    while ( (UARTFR & (1<<5)) != 0) continue; //while full wait
    UARTDR = ch;
}
```

Pros and cons to use 0x20 or (1<<5), obviously both are the same. Both offer better readability and validation depending on the individual and how they use/read a manual, etc.

The problem I found is if you hold the key down on the keyboard and repeat into the virtual terminal it appears it overflows the simulated rx buffer and an explosion of characters come out.  You don't have this problem on real hardware.  qemu is open source, so you can easily just go read the code to see what is going on.  Possible that it wants an more accurate/correct uart init, since the uart on real hardware would not work with this code as written. a uart init is needed.

Understand that absolutely none of this has to do with a cortex-m3, the fact there is a cortex-m3 is in this chip is irrelevant with respect to the uart, the uart is either created or purchased ip by Luminary Micro which was then assimilated by TI.  the cortex-m3 is just the processor core, the bulk of the code and documentation, etc have nothing to do with the cortex-m3.  In that this answer is written in English using an English alphabet yet this answer does not dwell on that fact.

And this answer could easily be written in another language using the alphabet for that language.  The cortex-m3 is just the mechanism in which you poke at control registers and make the peripherals do things.  chips like this with a purchased ip core get the core from one vendor and the rest of the chip is either the chip vendors IP or a collection of other third party ip, or a combination.

Your title question makes no sense since the cortex-m3 doesn't have a uart.  Your actual question is related to the LM3S811 CHIP (not board) and the QEMU implementation of that, ideally with a qemu version, but at a minimum: "How to echo data through the LM3S811 QEMU simulation"

Comment: also you should have edited the prior question instead of writing another question, if you dont have enough reputation points to edit then that is understandable.

Comment: As it stands the code snippets will not work; a condition like `(UARTFR & 0x10) == 1` will never be met because the expression `UARTFR & 0x10` will never have bit zero set.  My own preference would be simply to dispense with the equality check and write e.g. `while (UARTFR & 0x10)`.